# PHP MGRS Conversion Formula/Library

Tags: web-mapping, coordinate-system, convert, php

Currently, the formula I'm using to convert MGRS to Lat/Long and vice versa is giving me slightly different results than most other conversion utilities.  It's usually between 10 to 30 feet off.  This isn't a very big difference, but it matters for the particular application of data.  I'm wondering if anyone knows of a simple library that does conversions between MGRS and Lat/Long or UTM.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

http://freegeographytools.com/2007/mgrsutmlatitude-longitude-converter

Comment: I'm not looking for a utility to perform the conversion.  I wanted to know if there was a PHP class out there.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/TOOLS/usng.shtml

which is also downloadable (including the FORTRAN source). USNG is a simplified version of MGRS. Datum is usually NAD83 and you don't have to handle the different letter schema based on the datum/ellipsoid. In MGRS, NAD27 data would have a different letter schema than NAD83.

Geotrans 3.0

http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/geotrans/index.html

which is in C or Java also has source code available.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommnend you to use [USNG](http://forums.arcgis.com/attachment.php?s=e0352c00e49f5750415267e7beefaca6&attachmentid=9336&d=1317847286) library to convert

LL to USNG (function LLtoUSNG(lat, lon, precision))

LL to MRGS (function LLtoMGRS(lat, lon, precision))

LL to UTM  (Note: UTM calculations are an intermediate step in LLtoUSNG conversions but can be used as seperate function if required)

and more, plus reverse